# Confused by async behavior

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, fetch

I'm using a try/catch to make some fetch requests, then I am extracting the title from the HTML and adding it to my object 'sleekResponse'
When I try to parse the body and add it to that object I'm having issues with the return value not including the title that I extracted from the HTML

I know this has something to do with asynchronicity, or my shallow understanding of Promises, but I can't tell why the return value is different from the value it's logging just before it's sent.

```
async function fetchUrl(url) {
  console.log(url);
  try {
    const myInit = {
      mode: 'cors'
    }

    let sleekResponse = {};

    await fetch(url, myInit).then(function (response) {
      sleekResponse.redirected = response.redirected;
      sleekResponse.status = response.status;
      return response;
    })
    .then((response) => titleWait(response))
    .then((res) => sleekResponse.title = res)

    function titleWait(response) {
      Promise.resolve(response.text()).then((res) => {
        a = res.split('<title>');
        b = a[1].split('</title>')
        sleekResponse.title = b[0];
        return sleekResponse;
      })
      console.log(sleekResponse);
      return sleekResponse;
    }

    console.log(sleekResponse); // This logs the correct value
    return sleekResponse; // when it's returned it doesn't show the title that was added
  } catch (err) {
    return `${err}`;
  }
}
```

I've tried so many things I don't remember everything that I tried. I know that I'm missing something that might be obvious, but I still don't understand why the console.log value is different from the value returned one line later.

Comment: titleWait doesn't _return_ the promise it (pointlessly) news up.

Comment: I suggest you use `async` and `await` consistently in the function, instead of switching to promise syntax.

Comment: `Promise.resolve(response.text())` is redundant. It should just be `response.text()`. In `titleWait`, you’re not awaiting the Promise, so `return sleekResponse;` will happen before `sleekResponse.title = b[0];`. There’s no point in using a separate function. `.split('<title>')` isn’t reliable. Just use `.then((response) => response.text()).then((html) => new DOMParser(html, "text/html").title).then((title) => sleekResponse.title = title)` instead, after the `fetch(`…`)`.

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask].

Comment: Although it is a bit confusing why you’re setting the `title` property on `sleekResponse` in two different places. `titleWait` returns the `sleekResponse` object, not a title, so why do you expect `.then((res) => sleekResponse.title = res)` to set the `title` property to a string? The result of the Promise also returning `sleekResponse` is completely ignored (no `await`, no preceding `return`, no assignment, nothing). You never return a title to set, only the object to set the title on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that `titleWait` doesn't return its own promise:

```js
    function titleWait(response) {
      return Promise.resolve(response.text()).then((res) => {
        a = res.split('<title>');
        b = a[1].split('</title>')
        sleekResponse.title = b[0];
        return sleekResponse;
      });
    }
```

It's still a very convoluted way to write it. This is better:

```js
    async function titleWait(response) {
      const res = await response.text());
      const a = res.split('<title>');
      const b = a[1].split('</title>')
      sleekResponse.title = b[0];
      return sleekResponse;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation! I should have taken a break yesterday, this seems so obvious after getting some sleep.

Answer (score -3):

i hope i can  a litel help

this basic fetch();

```js
const response = await fetch('your url') 

const data = await response.json();

console.log(data);
```

Comment: How is JSON related here?

Comment: if this not worked for json , change your json to object and try  up code , but i always other data in other site , i use this .